# achieving firstlevel cache in database via JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've the following setup (not tested) because I am afraid this will break. I want to achieve some sort of first level cache find in Database before I do a check in LDAP

**(1) How to loop through table/getUserEmail in the service code**, I am afraid there can be multiple rows coming in from database. If not, how to prevent it.
**(2) how to improve this or make it fool-proof.**

I am new to JPA/Spring-boot in general, so please help

**ENTITY**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userEmailCache")
public class userEmailCacheEntity {


    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userId;
// getter and setters redacted
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
@Repository

    public interface userEmailCacheEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<userEmailCacheEntity, Long>  {
    
        @Query(value="SELECT "
                + "userEmail "
                + "FROM userEmailCache "
                + "WHERE userId = :param01 ")
        String getUserEmail(@Param("param01") String param01);
    }
```

**SERVICE**

```
        @Autowired
        userEmailCacheEntityRepository repo;
        //code redacted
           //check in database and get email
            String strEmail = repo.getUserEmail(userId);
              //if not found in database
              if(strEmail == null) {
                //fetch email from LDAP/Active Directory
              }
              else {
                LOG.info("[I] Found in DB {} : {}", userId, strEmail);
            }
//save in Database
    userEmailCacheEntity file = new userEmailCacheEntity();
    file.setUserEmail(strEmail);
    file.setUserId(userId);
    repo.save(file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java uses CamelCase and capitalized class names by convention, so I have changed that.

You don't need to use `@Column(unique = true)` on an `@Id` - this means it's the primary key and it **has to be unique**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userEmailCache")
public class UserEmailCacheEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String userEmail;
    private String userId;
// getter and setters redacted
}
```

So you say `userId` is not unique? That's a bit of a misnomer I think, since IDs should be used to identify things. Anyway, you might want to make sure that you have an Index on your `userId` column in your Database, to speed up searches.

You did get the return type wrong though. Since you said there can be multiple E-Mails per `userId`, you need to return a list:

```
@Repository
public interface UserEmailCacheEntityRepository 
        extends JpaRepository<UserEmailCacheEntity, Long>  {

    @Query(value="SELECT "
            + "userEmail "
            + "FROM userEmailCache "
            + "WHERE userId = :uid ")
    List<String> getUserEmails(@Param String uid);

}
```

And then you also need to handle a result with multiple entries:

```
@Autowired
userEmailCacheEntityRepository repo;

//check in database and get email
List<String> strEmails = repo.getUserEmails(userId);

//if not found in database
if (strEmails.isEmpty()) {
    //fetch email from LDAP/Active Directory
    String ldapMail = retrieve();
} else {
LOG.info("[I] Found in DB {} results for {}: {}", strEmail.size(), userId, strEmail);
}

//save in Database
UserEmailCacheEntity file = new userEmailCacheEntity();
file.setUserEmail(ldapMail);
file.setUserId(userId);
repo.save(file);
```

I can't tell you how to handle multiple returned E-Mails, since I don't know what you are doing with them (although that design seems strange).

And why did you call your new entity "file"? It's not a file, isn't it?

Comment: its not a file. I used the following function to get around Optional<LDAPUserEmailEntity> findFirst1ByUserIdOrderByEmailAsc(String userId);